# Tar and upload multiple files to S3 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, archive

I have two files in separate location that I want to zip (**tar.gz**) and upload to a S3 bucket.

The current location of the files looks like following in my file system

```
File 1: src/textFile/sample.txt
File 2: src/jsonData/sample.json
```

I need to store the above two files in a zipped folder and upload it to S3. Is there a way I can stream directly to S3 without creating an additional `tar.gz` file in the file system?

I was reading about using the `tar-stream` or `tar-fs` package, but not sure if this the right approach.

My current S3 **class**

```
class AwsS3Service {
    private config ={
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: "us-east-1"
    }

    FOLDER = "zip";
    BUCKET = "xxxxxxxx";

    private getBucket;
    constructor(){
        this.getBucket = new S3(this.config);
    }

    public async uploadFile(file: Buffer, key: string): Promise<Boolean>{
        try{
            const params = {
                Bucket: this.BUCKET,
                Key: this.FOLDER +  key,
                Body: file,
                ACL: 'private'
            }
    
            const data = await this.getBucket.upload(params);

        }catch(err){
            console.log(`Couldn't upload the file: ${err.message}`);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```